# Wordpress: My JS files are not executing any of their code, nor do they return a 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Here's my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = jQuery(window);

    console.log("Pre-page height: " + $window.height());
    jQuery('.main-content .home-block').height($window.height());

    $window.on('resize', function(){
        console.log("Resize event height: " + $window.height());
        jQuery('.main-content .home-block').height($window.height());
    });
});
```

This is my current `<head>` code:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title><?php cs_wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php if( ! cs_get_option( 'non_responsive' ) ) { ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
    <?php } ?>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" />
    <!-- Start of imported scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/customjs/main.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/panelsnap/jquery.panelsnap.js" />
    <!-- End of imported scripts -->
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <?php if ( is_search() || is_404() ) { echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />'; } ?>
    <?php if ( cs_get_option( 'favicon' ) ) { echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'. cs_get_option( 'favicon' ) .'" />'; } ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
```

My console is clean, and there is no error visible. Nothing strange is happening on my page as well. What's the problem here?

Comment: Do you see something in your console.log(...)?

Comment: @Mivaweb it's a late edit but I just answered that in my edit, no I don't unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script ?

Comment: The javascript side of it [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/juwrwz42/) for me.  My advise to you would be to rewrite the page adding in one piece at a time.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is present on your page? Maybe you are saving the code, but on a different page?

Comment: To the respective questions of @CaioFelipePereira and brance, No and yes. It seems like a normal alert in console works, but anything with jQuery doesn't, even though I clearly have jQuery in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here's a lesson well learned:

**Always check your jQuery CDN.**

It wasn't working. A normal `console.log` or `alert` gave me a response, but anything with a jQuery selector would derp out.

I switched from the jQuery CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" />
```

To the Google CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it started working.